# Android TV App not displaying in Google Play Store

Tags: android, kotlin, television, leanback

Below is my manifest file, I have included all the necessary code as per the [document](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start) but still the app is not displaying in the play store search. I searched using the appId for my Alpha build using my test account which i have included in the tester list.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.package">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />


    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="true" />


    <application
        android:name=".TestApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:banner="@drawable/logo"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:directBootAware="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MediaActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.CodeActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.CodeAndroidStickActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I tried setting the `android.software.leanback` field to both true and false, but still not getting displayed

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution of this issue ? please share it with us.

Answer (score 1):

In your app manifest, you must declare that a touch screen is not required, as shown this example code; otherwise, your app won't appear in Google Play on TV devices.

```
<manifest>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
              android:required="false" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: Have set Touch screen is not required still app is not showing in playstore on MiTV Stick and displays that "App is Not Compatible with this device". The app's Android manifest has "<category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER"/>" AND "<uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback" android:required="true" />".

Answer (score 0):

Declare leanback to true and touchscreen to false in your manifest file.

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="true" />
```

Also finish setup Android TV on Form Factors section in Play console like what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69777175/12284493) done